# Не обновляется ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

Не нашел ни одного похожего вопроса, кроме тех где изменения не происходят при добавление элемента. А у меня проблема заключается в том что есть

```
public ObservableCollection<Note> Notes {get; set;}
```

В конструкторе этого класса инициализирую этот список

```
Notes = new ObservableCollection<Note>(helper.GetChildNodes());
```

И все в порядке. Но во время выполнения программы необходимо повторить кусок кода, который написан выше, но при этом `helper.GetChildNodes()` уже возвращает другие значения.

Но список почему-то не обновляет привязку с ListBox

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" DataContext="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote}">
```

Что делать? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: `необходимо повторить кусок кода` - полностью строку `Notes = new ObservableCollection<Note>(helper.GetChildNodes());`? Если да, то это ошибка, ибо привязка происходит к тому объекту, который создан ранее, а вы его переинициализируете через `new`.

Comment: Хмм? Не особо понимаю о чем вы, но эта коллекция находится в классе MainViewModel, который наследуется от BaseViewModel, а он уже от INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: EvgeniyZ а как тогда быть. Я пытался очистить коллекцию а потому через CopyTo добавить новые значения, но также ничего не происходило.

Comment: У вас `Notes` должна быть инициализирована только 1 раз, все. Дальше вы ее инициализацию не трогаете. Добавление производите через `.Add()` и подобные методы. То есть самый лучший вариант, это пройтись по `helper.GetChildNodes()` циклом и каждый элемент уже добавлять в `Notes`. Либо сделать событие, через которое вы будете добавлять новые объекты (опять же через `.Add()`.

Comment: Лааааднооо. Так а почему CopyTo не работает ведь 1 раз инициализация идет.

Comment: А как вы делаете `CopyTo`?

Comment: Либо Notes должно оповещать об изменении с помощью INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: EvgeniyZ, Notes.CopyTo(helper.GetChildNodes(), 0);

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Вы немного не так понимаете суть этого метода. Смотрите, [простой пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaqi0.png) выдает [результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAlGo.png). Как видите в массиве `array` заменились все значения теми, что были в `ObservableCollection`. То есть `.CopyTo()` копирует из текущего массива в указанный. Вам надо делать обратное, написав `helper.GetChildNodes().CopyTo(...)`. Но тут получаете одно но, этот метод принимает на вход массив и вам придется сделать `Notes.ToArray()`, а это уже создание нового объекта. P.S. Не забывайте ставить `@` перед ником.

Comment: Понял спасибо за помощь!